# How can I change the default port in react from 3000 to another port?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

### how to change react default port 3000 to others port ?

By default, a ReactJS app runs on port 3000. An Express.js app also runs on the same port 3000. If you were to run the two apps simultaneously, there would be conflicts. You need to change the port of one of them.
In ReactJS, the easiest way to alter the port number is by setting an environment variable named PORT to the desired number via the terminal. As an example, here we change the port number to 5000.

if you use In Linux and Mac terminals, it would be

```
$export PORT=5000
```

or if you use In Windows, the command is slightly different

```
$env:PORT=5000
```

and finally start npm

```
npm start
```

#### NB: It is for .env file

If you want to modify your package.json
Default is

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

and modify by

```
  "start": "PORT=2000 react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

and finally run again

### I use this

modify your package.json Linux and MacOS :

```
"start": "PORT=3006 react-scripts start"
```

or

```
"start": "export PORT=6000 react-scripts start"
```

or Windows

```
"start": "set PORT=6000 && react-scripts start"
```

and finally restart npm

I try to change default port by using this and success, So you can try

## If better solution Please help me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A better way would be to add a `.env` file to your root folder. In it, just write:

`PORT=<YOUR_PORT>`.

This way is better, since you don't have to account for all operating systems. It will just work for all of them because of the way `create-react-app` works.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can define a `"dev"` option to start your server which will `"concurrently"` handle your react.js process and node.js server

By doing this, you will not bother yourself with defining `env` variables.

Here is backend package json file, scripts part. Then, just type: `npm run dev` on command line:

```
  "scripts": {
    "server": "node server.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix ./frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

`frontend` folder contains react project and it is at the same level with `package.json`, that's why it is `./`