# Miltiple Docker React Apps connect to relevent Docker Backend in same machine conflict

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask, proxy

Two Groups of frontend-backend can not run at the same time in one linux machine.

`ppm-backend error log: get /main.43ac74709aa61536a874.hot-update.json http/1.1 404 -`

Group 1
docker network: daat-network (bridge)
container: daat-frontend (-p 3000:3000)
container: daat-backend (-p 5001:5000)

Group 2
docker network: ppm-network (bridge)
container: ppm-frontend (-p 3100:3000)
container: ppm-backend (-p 5100:5100)

Inspect **daat-network**:

```
    "Containers": {
    "4bd96d854b70e943b2877387537d751c1691f797e55d423acac2a8b6101bd9d5": {
        "Name": "daat-backend",
        "EndpointID": "d35674387616c0884ecc399ad5a4b6fcc340d1907b45327057be07b69b26d27a",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
        "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    },
    "b87f477a22b5177dc15b8b36d2dccde9c9e583ac0771fc43c78e54b7860c77a3": {
        "Name": "daat-frontend",
        "EndpointID": "38297b9315ad534c537d47dc78018e067b652fbf576030e88cf67418f873ab16",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
        "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    }
},
```

Inspect **ppm-network**

```
"Containers": {
    "32ba229fb32fe56b39a566ae1681da80c4ebe336f045b96cdda7756b64a741c9": {
        "Name": "ppm-frontend",
        "EndpointID": "b225a2857fc400d64fdfa06deec79c37fc6d619fc1744d48bc592b6b7788280f",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
        "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    },
    "eb3a54e5d1bdb473a478d198c679ad0fcaa4eb1be2e623cea99b42cd1aa47ce4": {
        "Name": "ppm-backend",
        "EndpointID": "2b8a3a962c85bba2d828c6a4db9ba10529057bc461bb2d7a773c90291b6b6691",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
        "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
        "IPv6Address": ""
    }
},
```

You can see the IP address of ppm-backend and daat-backend are different, but they still conflict.

**4 cases 4 behaviors**:

case 1: daat-frontend; daat-backend **success**

case 2: ppm-frontend; ppm-backend **success**

case 3: daat-backend; ppm-frontend; ppm-backend **success**

case 4: daat-frontend; daat-backend; ppm-frontend; ppm-backend **fail**

Step to reproduce:

1. Start Group One
2. Start Group Two

**Error Result:
ppm-frontend continuously refresh page quickly**

Error Log shown in ppm-backend (Over and over again while refreshing):

```
[2023-09-08-04:37:11][werkzeug][INFO][_internal.py] 172.19.0.3 - - [08/Sep/2023 04:37:11] "GET /main.b13c410dc743bccc6131.hot-update.json HTTP/1.1" 404 -
[2023-09-08-04:37:12][Priority Mangement][ERROR][app.py] [HTTPException] stack:
[2023-09-08-04:37:12][Priority Mangement][ERROR][app.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1785, in dispatch_request
    self.raise_routing_exception(req)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1767, in raise_routing_exception
    raise request.routing_exception  # type: ignore
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 351, in match_request
    result = self.url_adapter.match(return_rule=True)  # type: ignore
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/routing/map.py", line 655, in match
    raise NotFound() from None
werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

[2023-09-08-04:37:12][werkzeug][INFO][_internal.py] 172.19.0.3 - - [08/Sep/2023 04:37:12] "GET /main.b13c410dc743bccc6131.hot-update.json HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

## More information:

**ppm-frontend**:
package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ppm-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://ppm-backend:5100/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  ... ...
)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
ENV http_proxy=http://ppm-backend:5100/
ENV https_proxy=http://ppm-backend:5100/
EXPOSE 3100
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Docker run command:
`docker run -d -p 3100:3000 --name ppm-frontend --network ppm-network --restart always IMAGE_NAME`
request like:

```
axios
  .get("/users/application-list")
  .then((response) => {
    const newApplicationItems = response.data;
    setApplicationItems(newApplicationItems.concat());
    setTmpItems(newApplicationItems.concat());
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    let errMsg = error.response.data;
    window.alert(errMsg);
  });
```

**ppm-backend**:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
... ...
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5100)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11.4-slim-bullseye
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl git gcc -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install pip --upgrade && pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5100
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

For daat-frontend and daat-backend, they use similar method to connect.
Differences are:

1. "proxy": "http://ppm-backend:5100/", **to** "proxy": "http://daat-backend:5000/",
2. docker network: ppm-network **to** daat-network
3. Dockerfile: ENV http_proxy=http://ppm-backend:5000/ **to** ENV http_proxy=http://daat-backend:5000/

It is okey to deploy group 1 and group 2 to different machine respectively.
They can run in diferent machine, but in same machine will crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this issues by changing ppm-frontend listening port from default(3000) even inside docker container

Using this solution, and conclusion:

> *If you were to run the two apps simultaneously, there would be conflicts.*

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60245994/how-can-i-change-the-default-port-in-react-from-3000-to-another-port][1]